# Can we introduce a comparative study between mathematics & philosophy here?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, analytic-philosophy

Can the form of human mind be hypothetically equated with that of a mathematical point?

Comment: According to [Descartes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/#MinRel)  mind and body are distinct substances precisely because mind has no extension.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, it is not for comparative studies, discussions, blog posts, etc., open-ended prompts are off-topic here. Questions are supposed to be pointed, narrowly scoped, answerable based on existing literature, and show some research effort, see our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: That's more or less what Leibniz proposed in his *New System* https://www.earlymoderntexts.com/assets/pdfs/leibniz1695c.pdf

Comment: @Conifold  since I am an existing member of mse, I need to have that much of common sense & I know I possess that. If u kindly pay your focus on my question once more you can find out that I've asked whether we can think of such a possibility of introducing a comparative study on the basis of that topic or not; I haven't asked to explain the study itself as an answer. Perhaps there are some notions which I can get to know from others & that'll be beneficial for me. The approach is nothing other than a QnA.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But where does the correlation lie? There is nothing mentioned related to body in the question.

Comment: Point is geometry and according to D, extension (i.e. geometry) is the essence of body. And body is contraposed to mind: they are two radically different kind of *substance*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I got your point properly. Thanks!

Comment: It may be relevant that one of the books by the Dalai Lama is titled' The World in a Single Atom'.

Comment: @PeterJ Is it available online as a soft copy? Can you please send me the link?

Comment: @SULAGNABARAT - I'm afraid I only do books so don't know any online versions. In the UK a public library will should be able to find you a copy. The relevance would be that for his philosophy extension is reducible, not fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

Although one can imagine "mind" and a "mathematical point" having some aspects in common, such as, being without length, breadth or height and perhaps having existence there may be other aspects they do not have in common.

All I would need is one aspect they do not have in common to make them different.  Consider that a mind allows for enough consciousness to make choices. A mathematical point does not have the ability to make a choice under a common sense understanding of a mathematical point.

So any attempt to reduce one to the other will likely fail unless one can resolve all of the discrepancies between minds and mathematical points regardless of their similarities.

Consider the question:

> So, can the figure of mind be equated with that of a mathematical point?

Since it is easy to imagine properties that are not common to both minds and mathematical points, it is not likely that they can be equated without first finding some way to resolve these differences between them.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your humble response. But I just wanna say that I'm trying to draw a 'structural' comparison in between those two entities- the mind & point. Similarities have been mentioned with respect to nothing but their figural form.

Comment: @SULAGNABARAT One might be able to find something interesting about looking at the similarities of both and ignoring their differences. One additional difference, at least as I see minds and points, is that points are very individuated. Minds may not be so separated. Our bodies individuate our minds, but unless our bodies *are* our minds, we may have more in common with each other than we realize.

Comment: Okay..getting it

Comment: @FrankHubeny - Are points separated? What are they separated by? More points? Then what separates them? The idea that a lot of points take up more space than one point doesn't add up in my calculations.  .

Comment: @PeterJ You raise a good point about questioning my use of "separated" in the comment above. Topologically, points on a real number line are "separated" based on the idea of the existence of disjoint neighborhoods about any two points (that are not the same point): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space.  What does that mean for human beings? We wouldn't be neighborhood-separable like points are. This idea may be more important for understanding humans than it is for points.

Comment: @FrankHubeny - Thanks. I'll check your link. I don't know much about the mathematics but this misconception of points (whereby points have extension and space is made out of them) causes havoc in metaphysics.